# Program doesn't have permission to read it's own config file?

Tags: permissions, sync

So I'm trying to run [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) (which is in /usr/bin) and whenever I start it I get this error

```
FATAL: Configuration: open /home/ryan/.config/syncthing/config.xml: permission denied
```

So why is it that a program doesn't have permission to run it's own config file, and what can I do to fix this?

If I run the program as sudo it works but I want to run syncthing as a service and if I try to do it as sudo it makes all these problems.

Comment: Who created the file `config.xml`? Whats the output of `namei -m /home/ryan/.config/syncthing/config.xml` ?

Comment: The problem is you ran it with sudo, and it created the file as root, so your regular user doesn't have permissions to read the file. You need to fix the permissions on the file, or remove it with sudo and then run syncthing again as a normal user.

Comment: Yup that did it!

Comment: dobey you want to put the thing you said as an answer and then I can accept it?

Comment: Note that on Ubuntu you should probably start syncthing using systemd. Do `sudo systemctl enable syncthing@myuser` to make it start on each boot, and `sudo systemctl start syncthing@myuser` to start it right away. The sudo is necessary for systemctl here, but the service will run syncthing itself as `myuser`. You can check the status with `systemctl status syncthing@myuser` and follow the logs with `journalctl -u syncthing@myuser -f` (might have to sudo that last command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have run it as sudo the first time because purging it and reinstalling and then running as my regular user for the first time after the reinstall fixed the problem.  Thanks to dobey for the help!

Comment: IMHO rather than answering you should have told @dobey to put his comment as an answer as that actually solved the issue..

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply `chown ryan:ryan /home/ryan/.config/syncthing/config.xml` ? No need to removing the file, just change ownership back to yourself, and 'chmod +x' it too